# $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)g(x)dm=0$ Implies $f=0$ a.e

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $f$ be an integrable function on  $\mathbb{R}$ such that for every continuous function $g$ on $\mathbb{R}$, $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)g(x)dm=0$. Prove that $f$ is zero almost everwhere in $\mathbb{R}$

I know if $f$ was a non negative function, then directly by taking $g$ as a constant function we have,
$\int f=0\Rightarrow f=0 $ a.e. But here there are no restrictions on $f$.

And $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}f=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}f^++\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}f^-$
where:
$f^+=\max\{f,0\}$

$f^-=\max\{-f,0\}$

So  I took $g(x)=\int\limits_{0}^xf(t)dt$

Hence  $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)g(x)dm=0$ implies  $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\int\limits_{0}^xf(t)dtdm=0$ and I'm trying to get an expression like $\int|f|=0$.
But I cannot see the correct path to do so. May be there is a totally different method...
Appreciate your help

Comment: Why not pick $g=f$?

Comment: Because $f$ need not to be continuous

Comment: Oh you are right, I missed that.

Comment: Can't you just take the derivative by $m$ of both sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a<b$. There exist  continuous function $g_n$ such that $g_n(x)=1$ for $a \leq x \leq b$, $0\leq g \leq 1$, $g(x)=0$ for $x >b+\frac 1n $ and $g(x)=0$ for $x <a-\frac  1n$. This gives $\int_a^{b} f(x)dx+a_n+b_n=0$ where $a_n$ is the integral of $fg$ from $a-\frac 1 n$ to $a$ and $b_n$ is the integral of $fg$ from $b$ to $b+\frac 1 n$. Show that $a_n \to 0$ and $b_n \to 0$ by noting that $\int_A f \to 0$ as $m(A) \to 0$. This gives us $\int_a^{b} f(x)dx=0$ whenever $a <b$. Hence $f(x)=0$ for almost all $x$. [Divide by $b-a$  and let $b \to a$. Use Lebesgue's Theorem. ].

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But can you please explain what exactly you meant by $0\leq g\leq 1$ in the first line

Comment: It means $0 \leq g(x) \leq 1$ for all $x$. There exists  piece-wise linear continuous function $g$ with these properties. Looking at the graph of such a function is useful.  @gune

Comment: Thank you but can you please also explain why is that $\int\limits_a^bf=0$ implies $f=0$ a.e? Isn't it a property for non negative functions?

Comment: If the integral is $0$ for all $a<b$ then $f=0$ a.e.This is a consequence of a theorem of Lebesgue which says that if $f$ is integrable then $\frac 1 {b-a} \int_a^{b} f(x)dx \to f(a)$ as $b \to a$ for almost all $a$. @gune

Comment: Ref.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem

Comment: Ah I didn't know that one. Thank you very much!